# Rails 4.0 image_tag size option not working

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I want to use image_tag size

app/helpers/application_helper.rb

```
def fooimage(size)
  image_tag size: "#{size}"
end
```

app/views/home/index.html.haml

```
=fooimage("large")
```

but,not working. why?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I do not believe that size takes in arguments in words (i.e. large, medium, etc).

You can modify your fooimage method a bit:

```
def fooimage(image_path, size)
  if size == "large"
    actual_size = "200x200"
  elsif size == "medium"
    acutual_size = "100x100"
  else
    actual_size = "50x50"
  end
  image_tag image_path, size: "#{actual_size}"
end
```

And, call it like...

```
<%= fooimage "logo.png", "large" %>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to supply the image filename as the first parameter to image_tag.

```
image_tag <filename>, size: <size>
```

For more info, please see:

http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/AssetTagHelper.html#method-i-image_tag